# How to require at least 1 checkbox for AngularJS Form Validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have an array of JSON objects which is displayed in a form. I would like to have the form validation work where a user has to select at least one checkbox for the entire form to be valid.

I know that the `ng-required` can be used but with the implementation I have, it means that all of them have to be selected for it to be valid.

Here is the code I have so far:

**index.html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in volunteerOptions">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" data-ng-model="item.selected" ng-required="true">{{ item.content }}</label>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!memberRegistrationForm.$valid">Submit</button>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.volunteerOptions = [
        { content : 'Content 1', selected : false },
        { content : 'Content 2', selected : false },
        { content : 'Content 3', selected : false },
        { content : 'Content 4', selected : false },
];
```

Any ideas on how I would be able to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add another scope property and use [`array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the `selected` are `true`. Then feed that scope property to `ng-required`. Something like

```
$scope.isOptionsRequired = function(){
  return !$scope.volunteerOptions.some(function(options){
    return options.selected;
  });
}

<input type="checkbox" value="" data-ng-model="item.selected" ng-required="isOptionsRequired()">
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect.

Comment: This is working fine. But how to show error message below the checkboxes. I used this one - `<div ng-show="projectForm.$submitted || projectForm.item_id.$touched">
                                    <span ng-show="projectForm.item_id.$error.required" class="text-danger">Select any Item.</span>
                                </div>` this error message working fine but when i applyed `item_id` in checkbox name property. I got all checked when i check any one. Please help me...