# Atleast select one check box in form validation using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my html

```
<form name="sales">
<div class="sale-type">
                            <p>Which would you like to sell?</p>
                            <fieldset class="md-form form-group">
                                <input ng-model="art.originalForSale" name="originalForSale" type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox2">
                                <label for="checkbox2">My Original ART</label>
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset class="md-form form-group">
                                <input ng-model="art.printForSale" name="printForSale" type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox22">
                                <label for="checkbox22">Prints of my ART</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="sales.$invalid" class="btn-form btn-next c-sprite" alt="Submit"></button>
</form>
```

I want to display validation message that shows at least one check box required how can i do it

found a solution from this question [How to require at least 1 checkbox for AngularJS Form Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181624/how-to-require-at-least-1-checkbox-for-angularjs-form-validation)

but it uses a script i want a solution without using scirpt

currently i  am using

```
<span  ng-show="part1.originalForSale.$error.required" class="error">Checkbox required</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that solve your problem:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<ng-form name="sales" ng-app >
  <div class="sale-type">
    <p>Which would you like to sell?</p>
    <fieldset class="md-form form-group">
      <input ng-model="art.originalForSale"  value="cb1" name="originalForSale" type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox2" ng-required="!art.printForSale">
      <label for="checkbox2">My Original ART</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="md-form form-group">
      <input ng-model="art.printForSale" value="cb2" name="printForSale" type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox22" ng-required="!art.originalForSale">
      <label for="checkbox22">Prints of my ART</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <span  ng-show="sales.$invalid" class="error">Checkbox required</span>
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="sales.$invalid" class="btn-form btn-next c-sprite" alt="Submit"></button>
</ng-form>
```

Comment: Strange!! its not working the error message still showing

Comment: When I run the code, the message is showing only if the both checkbox is unmarked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ngRequired`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) directive. There is a simple example.

```
<input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked1" ng-required="isChecked2">
<input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked2" ng-required="isChecked1">
```

You can use [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) for validation message

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.checkbox1.$error || myForm.checkbox2.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not select a checkbox !</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't worked always shows the error message even if checkbox checked

Comment: <span ng-show="part1.originalForSale.$invalid || part1.printForSale.$invalid" class="error">Atleast one checkbox required</span>

Comment: This is not what i wrote. Use same directives and `$error` variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147167/discussion-between-jabaa-and-burak-akyildiz).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below?

```
<span  ng-show="!(art.printForSale || art.originalForSale) " class="error">Checkbox required</span>
```

Use this with $dirty if you want to show the message after submit form.

Answer (score -1):

write required attributes in input tag for showing msg

```
    <span ng-show="frmRegister.name.$dirty && frmRegister.name.$error.">this is req...</span>
```

Comment: I need to check either one of the field